# $.post return null value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I use $.post in $.post !

But second $.post return null value !

JQuery Code :

```
var id;
$.post('1.php', {id:id}, function(data){
    var stat;
    $.post('2.php', {stat:stat}, function(newdata){
        alert(newdata);
    });
});
```

2.php code :

```
if(isset($_POST['stat'])){
    echo "test";
}
```

Comment: You have a syntax error. `{stat:stat,` -> `{stat:stat},`. Is that issue present in your real code?

Comment: `var stat;` and next line `stat:stat` so stat is undefined

Comment: @A.Wolff it shouldn't really matter since the PHP Code is returning `test`

Comment: Sorry !!! edit first post . in real code closed } !

Comment: @Mohammad In that case, check your javascript console and network tab for errors.

Comment: @Spokey it doesn't matter with OP's issue, i just post it as comment because it could be the following question on SO of Mohammad... ;)

Comment: @JasonP in console not found error and in network all post is OK

Comment: is that all the code you PHP page has? it doesn't really seem to be a problem with the code itself.. here a similar example http://jsfiddle.net/HPEj9/

Comment: @Spokey yes php file is correct

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any more code to show, where are you defining your variables?.

Your stat var is inside the $.post scope, so it wouldn't be global.

Also you have an error in your code, missing a curly brace after stat

Comment: How fixed it ? write stat var before first $.post ?

Comment: Yeah, put them inside the function.